# So that vs so to express purpose

Tags: adverbials

> He studied hard  __ he could go to a good university

A. because

B. in order to

C. so

D. so that

I guess D is the "right" answer.

According to what I have learned, "so" and "so that" can both express purpose, and usually there is a preference for "so that".

Do you think the preference in this context is so strong as to deem D is the only correct answer？

Comment: [link](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=studied+hard+so+that+he%2Cstudied+hard+so+he&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3)

Comment: We can use a finite clause with **so that.**   In informal style we can leave out **that.**

Comment: Why the downvotes for both answers?

Comment: @BillJ  I'm also in the dark. I suspect it's someone's prank.

Comment: Why do you think "in order to he could go" is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is D.

You can say either of these:

- She exercises so that she can lose weight. (purpose)
- She exercises so she can lose weight. (purpose)

The word (that) is optional.

In other words, anytime you can say 'so that', you can also shorten it to 'so'. However, you cannot use 'so that' if you are talking about the effect (result) of an action (you can only use so). For example:

- It was cheap so that I bought it. (wrong)
- It was cheap so I bought it. (correct- because are talking about the result, not purpose)(we are talking about the result, not purpose)

Comment: The preposition "in order" is OK too, "So that" is not a constituent,' it's just "so" that is the preposition. "That" belongs in the clause that is complement to "so".

Comment: @BillJ, "In order" is OK, but the options do not have an "in order". If you mean the option "B" has "in order to", unfortunately it would not work here.

Comment: I realise that. In all probability, the question is from some naff exercise set by a non-native speaker. The OP needs to be aware that "in order" is fine and that the "to" belongs in the clause that is complement to it.

Answer (score -2):

> *He studied hard in order that/ so (that) he could go to a good university*].

So it's expressing purpose. In which case, the adjunct consists of a preposition phrase with either "in order" or "so" as head with, here, a finite clause as complement.

"Because" is the odd one out in your list of choices since it only occurs in reason adjuncts, not in purpose ones.